# cudaMemcpy to host for device-allocated memory still not possible?

Tags: c++, memory, cuda

I have a data structure with pointers (think linked lists). Its size can't be determined before launching the kernel that reads the input data. So I allocate data on the device during input processing.
However, trying to copy that data back to host fails. From what I could gather, this is because there is a limitation in CUDA that does not allow device-allocated memory to be accessed by the runtime API. That information, however, was for CUDA 4 with *"a fix coming soon"*. Does anyone know if that fix or a workaround ever came? I can't seem to find any recent information on this.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
#include <cstdio>

__device__ int *devData;

__global__ void initKernel()
{
    devData = new int[6];
    devData[0] = 0;
    devData[1] = 1;
    devData[2] = 2;
    devData[3] = 3;
    devData[4] = 4;
    devData[5] = 5;
}

__global__ void printKernel()
{
    printf("Testing device: %d\n", devData[3]);
}

int main()
{
    initKernel<<<1,1>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    printKernel<<<1,1>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    int *devAddr;
    cudaGetSymbolAddress((void **)&devAddr, devData);

    int *hostData = new int[6];
    cudaMemcpy(hostData, devAddr, 6*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost)); //cudaErrorInvalidValue (invalid argument)
    //same error with: cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(hostData, devData, 6*sizeof(int));

    printf("Testing host: %d\n", testHost[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

This throws a *cudaErrorInvalidValue* for cudaMemcpy (same for cudaMemcpyFromSymbol). This does not throw an error when I use `__device__ int devData[6];` instead of `__device__ int *devData;` and prints 3 as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's still not possible.

This is documented in [the programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#interoperability-host-memory-api).

> In addition, device malloc() memory cannot be used in any runtime or driver API calls (i.e. cudaMemcpy, cudaMemset, etc).

If you have data in allocations that were created by in-kernel `malloc()` that you wish to transfer to the host, you will need to transfer that data first to a device memory allocation (or managed allocation), before copying to host or using in host code.

The same comments and all aspects of usage for in-kernel `malloc` apply equally to in-kernel `new` as well as in-kernel `cudaMalloc`.